# redirect is not working in codeigniter _construct function

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, construct

I am facing a problem using redirect in _construct function, 
In timesheet controller I wrote the following code and I am getting an error in the browser "

> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
>   accept
>       cookies.

Here is my code

```
class Timesheet extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('timesheet_model');
        //$this->load->library('auth');
        $username=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        //$this->load->model('login_model');
        if($username['fullname']!=""){
        redirect('timesheet');

        }
        else{
        redirect('login');
        }

    }
```

Please help me to find a way to get rid of this problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're going around in a loop.

You check to see if the fullname element in your $username array is empty and, if it is, you redirect back to the same controller. I'm willing to bet it goes around in a circle like that for a while before the webserver throws up the error you mention.

If I'm reading what you're trying to do correctly, wouldn't you call another function within your Timesheet constructor if the fullname element is present to show whatever information it is that you're trying to display?

I'd suggest changing your logic to do the following:

```
if($username['fullname'] == ""){
    redirect('login');
    }
    else{
    //go to another controller method here
    }
```

Comment: Ya thanks. I realized just a few minutes ago. And I mentioned it in my answer. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it. The error is just because of I am redirecting to same controller where I have written the code. Everytime when it redirects to timesheet it enters into the construct function and it redirects again to timesheet. And the same thing is working like an endless loop.

So the fault was redirecting to the same controller.

I

Answer (score 0):

use redirect like this : `redirect('timesheet', 'refresh');`